# Read a csv that has non delimited text and blank lines above column headers and the bottom of the file using Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dataframe

I am trying to read a pipe delimited file using Pandas read_csv. However the files may or may not come with non delimited text either on the top or the bottom of the file.

I have tried:

```
pd.read_csv('file_sample.csv', sep='|', error_bad_lines=True)
```

However that does not work.

I am aware that I can read the file using the csv library and read line by line to confirm that the row is valid. Unfortunately I need a non looping solution, preferably using Pandas.
Thank you for your help

```
(60084 row(s) affected)



(30723 row(s) affected)


(41701 row(s) affected)



(171209 row(s) affected)

(17348 row(s) affected)


ProductId|ModelId|ProgramId|BranchId|AdvisorId|TotalAssets|NewAssets|AdditionAssets|ConversionNewAssets|TerminatedAssets
102abc|1|100|xyz|vbd|100|1900|0|10|0
103abc|1|100|xyz|vbd|150|1905|0|10|0
104abc|1|100|xyz|vbd|200|1910|0|10|0
102abc|1|100|xyz|vbd|250|1915|0|10|0
103abc|1|100|xyz|vbd|300|1920|0|10|0
104abc|1|100|xyz|vbd|350|1925|0|10|0
102abc|1|100|xyz|vbd|400|1930|0|10|0
103abc|1|100|xyz|vbd|450|1935|0|10|0

(1648248 row(s) affected)
```

Comment: Can you share an example of the file? It isn’t clear in your post which text is part of the file, and which parts are your comments.

Comment: Hi AMC, Thank you for getting back to me. I edited the question by adding a sample of how the csv looks like.

Comment: Alright, so the `(n row(s) affected)` is the “extra” text you don’t need?

Comment: Thats right, along with x number of empty lines in between

Comment: Is there any way to identify just the CSV part?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `comment = '('` it ignore lines start with `(` and consider its as comment.
- `skip_blank_lines = True` Blank line is by default ignored. As `skip_blank_lines` default value is `True`.

See here more optional parameters [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_table.html#pandas-read-table)

```py
>>> df = pd.read_csv('file_sample.csv', sep='|', comment='(')
>>> df
  ProductId  ModelId  ...  ConversionNewAssets TerminatedAssets
0    102abc        1  ...                   10                0
1    103abc        1  ...                   10                0
2    104abc        1  ...                   10                0
3    102abc        1  ...                   10                0
4    103abc        1  ...                   10                0
5    104abc        1  ...                   10                0
6    102abc        1  ...                   10                0
7    103abc        1  ...                   10                0

[8 rows x 10 columns]
```